# Check Values in columns for certain time span using timestamps from another column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, posixct

I have a df which consists of three columns, first one contains unique IDs, second one numeric Values and the last one date and time in POSIXct format. See below.

Ive tried to provide the first 10 observations using dput. I hope this works. Note that I had to delete the internal.selfref etc.

```
> dput(bp2s[1:10])
structure(list(HADM_ID = c(100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 
                                 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L), VALUE = c(112L, 
                                                                                                  120L, 121L, 112L, 106L, 109L, 80L, 89L, 85L, 99L), time = structure(c(5976682620, 
                                                                                                                                                                        5976684000, 5976687600, 5976691200, 5976694800, 5976698400, 5976785280, 
                                                                                                                                                                        5976788400, 5976790200, 5976792000), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to check each ID individually, whether at any point the VALUE stays below 100 for at least half an hour. The results should then be displayed in a new column ("BELOW") in Boolean with TRUE for < 100 for half an hour or more and FALSE if not. The Boolean value should be placed in the row of the starting point.
The result should then look like this:

```
   HADM_ID VALUE                TIME BELOW
1:  100210    92 2159-05-26 08:40:00 TRUE
2:  100210    98 2159-05-26 09:00:00 FALSE
3:  100210   105 2159-05-26 09:12:00 FALSE
4:  100889    92 2166-08-15 14:50:00 FALSE
5:  100889    98 2166-08-15 15:00:00 FALSE
6:  100889   101 2166-08-15 15:15:00 FALSE
7:  100520    89 2133-02-03 14:15:00 TRUE
8:  100520   102 2133-02-03 15:15:00 FALSE
```

Using the *UPDATED* tidyverse proposal: Time diff is working and the first time the value stayed < 100 for 30 minutes+ is detected correctly(observation 7). Note, however, the next two observations(8 & 9) are still < 100 and stay < 100 and yet they are marked as FALSE.

```
 HADM_ID VALUE time                time_diff   grp below
     <int> <int> <dttm>              <drtn>    <int> <lgl>
 1  100210   112 2159-05-24 15:37:00   23 mins     1 FALSE
 2  100210   120 2159-05-24 16:00:00   60 mins     2 FALSE
 3  100210   121 2159-05-24 17:00:00   60 mins     3 FALSE
 4  100210   112 2159-05-24 18:00:00   60 mins     4 FALSE
 5  100210   106 2159-05-24 19:00:00   60 mins     5 FALSE
 6  100210   109 2159-05-24 20:00:00 1448 mins     6 FALSE
 7  100210    80 2159-05-25 20:08:00   52 mins     6 TRUE 
 8  100210    89 2159-05-25 21:00:00   30 mins     6 FALSE #should be TRUE since Value stays under 100 for next 30 min
 9  100210    85 2159-05-25 21:30:00   30 mins     6 FALSE #should be TRUE see above 
10  100210    99 2159-05-25 22:00:00   30 mins     6 FALSE
```

Using the UPDATED data.table solution I get the following result which looks spot on.

```
HADM_ID VALUE                time            timenext grp BELOW
 1:  100210   112 2159-05-24 15:37:00 2159-05-24 15:37:00   1 FALSE
 2:  100210   120 2159-05-24 16:00:00 2159-05-24 16:00:00   1 FALSE
 3:  100210   121 2159-05-24 17:00:00 2159-05-24 17:00:00   1 FALSE
 4:  100210   112 2159-05-24 18:00:00 2159-05-24 18:00:00   1 FALSE
 5:  100210   106 2159-05-24 19:00:00 2159-05-24 19:00:00   1 FALSE
 6:  100210   109 2159-05-24 20:00:00 2159-05-24 20:00:00   1 FALSE
 7:  100210    80 2159-05-25 20:08:00 2159-05-25 21:00:00   2  TRUE
 8:  100210    89 2159-05-25 21:00:00 2159-05-25 21:30:00   2  TRUE
 9:  100210    85 2159-05-25 21:30:00 2159-05-25 22:00:00   2  TRUE
10:  100210    99 2159-05-25 22:00:00 2159-05-25 22:30:00   2  TRUE
11:  100210    89 2159-05-25 22:30:00 2159-05-25 23:00:00   2 FALSE
12:  100210   102 2159-05-25 23:00:00 2159-05-25 23:00:00   3 FALSE
```

Regards

Comment: With data that contains spaces, it really helps to provide the sample data in a less ambiguous format using `dput(x)`. (Two reasons: if any cells have embedded spaces, we have to do a bit more work just to be able to use the data; sometimes blank space at the beginning or end of cells can be lost; and copying the text of it from here does not `class` the data appropriately. All of these problems are perfectly resolved when you post the output from `dput(x)` or `dput(head(x))` as appropriate.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a revised answer using `tidyverse`. The code has been modified to give a consistent result with @r2evans answer.

After grouping by your unique ID, add a column with the next row's time when `VALUE` below 100.

Then, create subgroups within each ID, to separate runs of `VALUE` less than 100 and those greater than 100.

Finally, for each of these subgroups, make `below = TRUE` when the `VALUE` is less than 100, and the difference in time between latest time for that subgroup and the row's time remains above 30 minutes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(HADM_ID) %>%
  mutate(time_next = if_else(VALUE >= 100, time, lead(time, default = last(time)))) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(VALUE < 100), .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(below = VALUE < 100 & difftime(max(time_next, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                        time, 
                                        units = "mins") > 30)
```

**Output**

```
  HADM_ID VALUE time                time_next             grp below
    <int> <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int> <lgl>
1  100210    92 2159-05-26 08:40:00 2159-05-26 09:00:00     1 TRUE 
2  100210    98 2159-05-26 09:00:00 2159-05-26 09:12:00     1 FALSE
3  100210   105 2159-05-26 09:12:00 2159-05-26 09:12:00     2 FALSE
4  100889    92 2166-08-15 14:45:00 2166-08-15 15:00:00     3 FALSE
5  100889    98 2166-08-15 15:00:00 2166-08-15 15:15:00     3 FALSE
6  100889   101 2166-08-15 15:15:00 2166-08-15 15:15:00     4 FALSE
7  100520    89 2133-02-03 14:15:00 2133-02-03 15:15:00     5 TRUE 
8  100520   102 2133-02-03 15:15:00 2133-02-03 15:15:00     6 FALSE
```

For second example dataset in question:

```
   HADM_ID VALUE time                time_diff   grp below time_next          
     <int> <int> <dttm>                  <int> <int> <lgl> <dttm>             
 1  100210   112 2159-05-24 15:37:00      1380     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 15:37:00
 2  100210   120 2159-05-24 16:00:00      3600     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 16:00:00
 3  100210   121 2159-05-24 17:00:00      3600     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 17:00:00
 4  100210   112 2159-05-24 18:00:00      3600     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 18:00:00
 5  100210   106 2159-05-24 19:00:00      3600     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 19:00:00
 6  100210   109 2159-05-24 20:00:00     86880     1 FALSE 2159-05-24 20:00:00
 7  100210    80 2159-05-25 20:08:00      3120     2 TRUE  2159-05-25 21:00:00
 8  100210    89 2159-05-25 21:00:00      1800     2 TRUE  2159-05-25 21:30:00
 9  100210    85 2159-05-25 21:30:00      1800     2 FALSE 2159-05-25 22:00:00
10  100210    99 2159-05-25 22:00:00      1800     2 FALSE 2159-05-25 22:00:00
```

Comment: This seems to work for the sample df. However, when I try to run that code over the whole df the grouping doesnt seem to work out

Comment: The first time this event occurs (observation 7) it is detected correctly. Note that the next two observation are also <100 for 30 minutes and are not marked as TRUE(see in my edited post using your solution).
I now tried to provide the data using dput. I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes the thenth should be TRUE since the elenth is also <100. The eleventh should be FALSE as the following is >100. I think r2evans solutions is working, but im checking manually right now to see.

Comment: Good - glad to hear his is working - would accept that answer. I'll look to see if I can modify what I have to match...

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben! You guys were indeed very helpful. Letting you know when Im done checking the results.

Comment: @ChickenlegJoe See edited answer - hopefully should be consistent with r2evans answer...

Comment: thanks. Ill try your updated solution to see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)
bp <- setDT(structure(list(HADM_ID = c(100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100889L, 100889L, 100889L, 100520L, 100520L), VALUE = c(92L, 98L, 105L, 92L, 98L, 101L, 89L, 102L), time = structure(c(5976852000, 5976853200, 5976853920, 6204797100, 6204798000, 6204798900, 5146744500, 5146748100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)))

bp[, timenext := shift(time, type = "lead", fill = time[.N]),
   by = HADM_ID
  ][, grp := cumsum(VALUE >= 100),
    by = .(HADM_ID)
  ][, BELOW := as.numeric(max(timenext,na.rm=TRUE) - time, units="mins") > 30,
    by = .(HADM_ID, grp)
  ][, c("timenext", "grp") := NULL ]
#    HADM_ID VALUE                time  BELOW
#      <int> <int>              <POSc> <lgcl>
# 1:  100210    92 2159-05-26 08:40:00   TRUE
# 2:  100210    98 2159-05-26 09:00:00  FALSE
# 3:  100210   105 2159-05-26 09:12:00  FALSE
# 4:  100889    92 2166-08-15 14:45:00  FALSE
# 5:  100889    98 2166-08-15 15:00:00  FALSE
# 6:  100889   101 2166-08-15 15:15:00  FALSE
# 7:  100520    89 2133-02-03 14:15:00   TRUE
# 8:  100520   102 2133-02-03 15:15:00  FALSE
```

---

**Updated** for new data:

```r
bp <- setDT(structure(list(HADM_ID = c(100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L, 100210L), VALUE = c(112L, 120L, 121L, 112L, 106L, 109L, 80L, 89L, 85L, 99L), time = structure(c(5976704220, 5976705600, 5976709200, 5976712800, 5976716400, 5976720000, 5976806880, 5976810000, 5976811800, 5976813600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L)))

bp[, timenext := fifelse(VALUE >= 100, time, shift(time, type = "lead", fill = time[.N])),
   by = HADM_ID
  ][, grp := rleid(VALUE < 100), by = .(HADM_ID)
  ][, BELOW := VALUE < 100 & as.numeric(max(timenext,na.rm=TRUE) - time, units="mins") > 30,
    by = .(HADM_ID, grp)
  ]
#     HADM_ID VALUE                time            timenext   grp  BELOW
#       <int> <int>              <POSc>              <POSc> <int> <lgcl>
#  1:  100210   112 2159-05-24 15:37:00 2159-05-24 15:37:00     1  FALSE
#  2:  100210   120 2159-05-24 16:00:00 2159-05-24 16:00:00     1  FALSE
#  3:  100210   121 2159-05-24 17:00:00 2159-05-24 17:00:00     1  FALSE
#  4:  100210   112 2159-05-24 18:00:00 2159-05-24 18:00:00     1  FALSE
#  5:  100210   106 2159-05-24 19:00:00 2159-05-24 19:00:00     1  FALSE
#  6:  100210   109 2159-05-24 20:00:00 2159-05-24 20:00:00     1  FALSE
#  7:  100210    80 2159-05-25 20:08:00 2159-05-25 21:00:00     2   TRUE
#  8:  100210    89 2159-05-25 21:00:00 2159-05-25 21:30:00     2   TRUE
#  9:  100210    85 2159-05-25 21:30:00 2159-05-25 22:00:00     2  FALSE
# 10:  100210    99 2159-05-25 22:00:00 2159-05-25 22:00:00     2  FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!Your solution works just fine with the sample df.

Comment: @ChickenlegJoe, see my edit for the updated data. If you don't understand my request for `dput`, try comparing (a) highlighting your sample data and converting it into usable data with `read.table` or such; with (b) copying and pasting my use of `bp <- setDT(structure(...))`. Note that that will override your local `bp`, so you may want to rename it, but ... it is instantly usable with appropriate POSIX columns, etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Im having a look into it, as Im not familiar with dput, this may take some time. Ill get back to it as soon as I figured it out.

Comment: I think the solution is working for the updated data but im checking manually to make sure. Note that i get a warning message but it doesnt seem to affect the results.

In `[.data.table`(bp2s, , `:=`(timenext, fifelse(VALUE >= 100, time,  :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar).

Comment: That warning has nothing to do with the question, it is because somehow you have somehow corrupted your `bp2` table. Again, nothing to do with this code. Try `setDT(bp2)` again, just to be sure and cement the data.table-requirements, and then try again.